# Configure rspec to show 'E' error when running an erroneous test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

**TL;DR: How can I stop rspec aborting all specs when it encounters an error?**

When running rails' built in testing suite, I get output similar to the following:

```
...F..F.EE...E

Finished in 0.64396 seconds
14 examples, 2 failures, 3 errors
```

The `.` represents a passing test, the `F` a failing test and the `E` an erroneous test. A failing test means the code of your rails application is failing, and an erroneous test means the code of your actual test is failing. Erroneous tests are never good.

What I do like about this though, is that when the program encounters an `E`, it keeps on going through all the other tests.

I'm using rpsec, and while I do like it, I sort of hate how, when it encounters an erroneous spec, it completely gives up the ghost, and quits all specs, like this:

```
12:39:37 - INFO - Running: spec
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!': Validation failed: Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:41:in `save!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `block in save!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
```

While I do like the error reporting, **I really want it to carry on running all specs when it encounters an erroneous spec**. Rather than the above output, I really want something along the lines of the following:

```
12:40:01 - INFO - Running: spec
...F..F..E

Failures:

  1) User A new user can be created email should == "awesomedog@hotmail.co.uk"
     Failure/Error: its(:email) { should == "awesomedog@hotmail.co.uk" }
       expected: "awesomedog@hotmail.co.uk"
            got: "awesomedozg@hotmail.co.uk" (using ==)
     # ./spec/model/user_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User A new user can be created should not be valid
     Failure/Error: it { should_not be_valid }
       expected valid? to return false, got true
     # ./spec/model/user_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Errors:

  1) `save!': Validation failed: Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)

Finished in 0.64396 seconds
10 examples, 2 failures, 1 error

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/model/user_spec.rb:11 # User A new user can be created email should == "awesomedog@hotmail.co.uk"
rspec ./spec/model/user_spec.rb:20 # User A new user can be created should not be valid
```

**I'm using factory-girl and factories in my specs, and data-base cleaner to clean my database between each spec. I'm using rspec-guard to run all specs on the event of any project file (apart from those in `tmp`,`log` or `db`) being saved.** Because rpsec keeps wimping out if it hits an error, I'm getting this error:

[How can I clean my database between erroneous rspec specs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295927/how-can-i-clean-my-database-between-erroneous-rspec-specs)

Basically, database-cleaner is configured to clean my database when a spec begins and when a spec finishes. Because rspec quits in the middle of a spec when it hits an error, database-cleaner doesn't detect that the spec has finished, and so never cleans my database. This means I have to manually empty it with my database shell.

I'd also prefer to see the state of all my other specs, even if one is erroneous! Rspec is really silly in this regard methinks!

Here are my factories and my spec:

spec/model/user_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
    context "Valid user" do
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_all_valid)

        subject { user }
        its(:first_name) { should == "Jimmy" }
        its(:last_name) { should == "Thehat" }
        its(:profile_name) { should == "Jimbohatboy893" }
        its(:email) { should == "awesomedog@hotmail.co.uk" }
        its(:password) { should == "thisisasupersecretpassword12234234" }
        its(:password_confirmation) { should == "thisisasupersecretpassword12234234" }
    end
end
```

spec/factories.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

    factory :user_with_all_valid, class: User do
        first_name "Jimmy"
        last_name "Thehat"
        profile_name "Jimbohatboy893"   
        email "awesomedog@hotmail.co.uk"
        password "thisisasupersecretpassword12234234"
        password_confirmation "thisisasupersecretpassword12234234"
    end
end
```

Comment: How exactly are you running the specs?  Are you doing `rspec spec` or `rake spec` ?  `rake spec` might help if you're not using it.

Comment: Excellent point, updated question

Comment: Are you using `stub!` or `before :all` at all?  These bleed from case to case.

Comment: still not clear how you are running tests - through guard?  I'd disable that while working this issue.  Tools like guard and spork can occasionally cause issues and why many folks stop using them.

Comment: Sorry, to be more specific I'm using rspec-guard.  So yeah all spec/tests are being initiated automatically by rspec-guard on the event of a file save.

Comment: What happens without it?  When you manually `rake spec`, what happens?

Comment: Exactly the same behavior. I don't think this is guard, it's an rspec issue. If I could get rspec to throw and 'E' and carry on with all specs rather than abort all specs I'm sure the error would go away. It's not stopping me working, everything works perfectly, it's just annoying that when rspec hits an error I've got to manually delete residual data from the erroneous test myself using a shell.

Comment: fyi, I've worked with close to 100 gems and I'm not familiar with the 'E'.  It's either `.` or `f` or `*`(pending).  Not saying the E doesn't exist, just commenting that I don't see it in use elsewhere

Comment: anyway please show the actual `the user_spec.rb` code to help you get an answer to your question.  We may be able to recommend a before or after block for cleanup but we need to see your existing code.

Comment: Okay, put my user_spec.rb up there now...the E is simply a possible result when using the rails integrated testing suite, I assumed rspec would have it too. I do prefer that behavior to rspec's way of aborting all specs if just one is gammy. There's further information in the link to my other question. I am just getting a workflow nailed down at the moment, I'm not actually testing a real system, so there's just the one spec. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: rspec doesn't abort all specs if one fails, you have to pass the --fail-fast option if you want that behavior, are you sure you have rspec properly configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is this line:

```
context "Valid user" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_all_valid)  # Right here!
  ...
```

Test setup should always be done in a `before` block; variable definition is done in a `let` block. Doing it in your test definition will cause rspec to fail as described. In general, you should only ever have rspec directives (before, after, let, subject, it, its, etc) in a `context` block. If you're running test setup, application code, whatever, you're going to open yourself up to this kind of problem. What you want is:

```
context "Valid user" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_all_valid) }
```

or:

```
context "Valid user" do
  before { @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_all_valid) }
```

The suite will then run the whole thing as expected, and report failures for the tests that fail to do their defined setup (the user definition) properly, rather than bombing out of the whole suite.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a unique email each time due to the validation on the model.
btw the other 7 or 8 are passing (dots).

Try adding:

```
new_user_time = Time.new
```

to save the current time.
Then pass that in to the create user factory.
Then use it to check that the users email is correct.

Comment: While this might fix the failing test, it doesn't address the question.

Comment: True I am going more for the answer to the question details than the title, but good point.

Answer (score 1):

Use sequences as detailed at: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences

Unique values in a specific format (for example, e-mail addresses) can be generated using sequences. Sequences are defined by calling sequence in a definition block, and values in a sequence are generated by calling FactoryGirl.generate:

```
# Defines a new sequence
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "person#{n}@example.com"
  end
end

FactoryGirl.generate :email
# => "person1@example.com"

FactoryGirl.generate :email
# => "person2@example.com"
...
```

The just have your spec check that part of the email address is correct, e.g. the `@something.com` or use a regular expression to compare, e.g. `match(/person.*@something\.com/)`