# Failing uniqueness validation with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, factory-bot

I'm having problems with FactoryGirl, I'm using sequence to avoid duplicating fields, but validations are failing anyway.

Output:

```
  1) CustomersController anonymous user GET #edit is redirected to signin when accessing edit form
     Failure/Error: get :edit, id: create(:customer)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken, Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:25:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

  3) Customer public class methods executes its methods correctly #find_by_id_or_name finds customer by name
     Failure/Error: let(:john) {create(:customer, name: 'John Doe X')}
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken, Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/models/customer_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/customer_spec.rb:38:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :customer do
    user
    name {Faker::Name.name}
    sequence(:mail) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
    address {Faker::Address.street_address}
    phone {Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number}
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) {|i| "example#{i}@example.com"}
    password {Faker::Internet.password(10)}
  end
end
```

These are the tests that are failing:

```
RSpec.describe Customer, type: :model do
    describe "public class methods" do
        let(:john) {create(:customer, name: 'John Doe X')}
        let(:frank) {create(:customer)}


    context "responds to its methods" do
      it "responds to #find_by_id_or_name" do
        expect(Customer).to respond_to(:find_by_id_or_name)
      end
    end

    context "executes its methods correctly" do
      context "#find_by_id_or_name" do
        it "finds customer by name" do
          customer = Customer.find_by_id_or_name('John Doe X')
          expect(customer).to eq john
        end
        it "finds customer by id" do
          customer = Customer.find_by_id_or_name(frank.id)
          expect(customer).to eq frank
        end
      end
    end
  end
end



RSpec.describe CustomersController, type: :controller do
  context "signed in user" do
    before :each do
      @user = create(:user)
    end
    describe "GET #edit" do
      it "renders :edit view" do
        get :edit, id: create(:customer).id
        expect(response).to render_template(:edit)
      end
    end

    describe "DELETE #destroy" do
      before :each do
        @customer = create(:customer, user: @user)
      end
      it "deletes record" do
        expect {delete :destroy, id: @customer.id}.to change(Customer, :count).by(-1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is happening to me all over my app. I just copied some tests that apply to Customer.

Thanks

Comment: Where is that `@user` instance variable coming from in the `before` block of the `DELETE #destroy` test? It may not be related to your problem, but instance variables can have super weird behavior in RSpec.

Comment: I just edited the question and added more code. It's instantiated in a before block that's run in the context

Answer (score 1):

My problem was related to not appropiately configuring database_cleaner. The configuration in this post solves the problem: [How can I clean my database between erroneous rspec specs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295927/how-can-i-clean-my-database-between-erroneous-rspec-specs)